# Flutter Keeping textformfields in array in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to keep data as Array in firestore by using more than one textformfield in Flutter. How can I send this data as an array? (The number of data is unknown. It could be any number.)

```
final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
class _RepairState extends State<Repair> {
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy - kk:mm').format(DateTime.now());
Future createRepairLogs(String title, String email, String desc, String date) async {

await _firebaseFirestore.collection("Repair").doc().set({
  'title': title,
  'email': email,
  'description':desc,
  'dateTime': date,
});
}
```

title will be an array. I want to have more than one data entry in the title.

Thanks for supporting.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your array to json which return string like this

```
String jsonArray=jsonEncode(["element1", "element2", "element3"]);
```

then you can obtained the array back by decoding the json

```
var list=jsonDecode(jsonArray);
```

Comment: did it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

change String title to List title

```
Future createRepairLogs(String title, String email, String desc, String date) async {
```